# How to access properties outside of an enum

Tags: swift, class, enums, properties, static

How can I access my class properties from within an enum contained in this class?

But as soon as I instantiate multiple MyClass, the _toggledOn is the same for all instances.

I hope there is some clean and swifty workaround I don't know. Anyways thank you in advance!

---

```
@IBDesignable
class MyClass: UIView, SomeProtocols {

    // MARK: - ENUM
    enum ToggleState {
        case on
        case off

        var color: UIColor {
            switch self {
            case .on:
                return _onColor
            default:
                return _offColor
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - STATICS
    private static var _onColor: UIColor = #colorliteral
    private static var _offColor: UIColor = #colorliteral

    // MARK: - IBSTUFF
    @IBInspectable var toggledOffColor: UIColor = #colorliteral {
        didSet {
            MyClass._offColor = toggledOffColor
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var toggledOnColor: UIColor = #colorliteral {
        didSet {
            MyClass._onColor = toggledOnColor
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var background: UIView!

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        toggleState = toggleState == .off ? .on : .off
    }

    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    var toggleState: ToggleState = .off {
        didSet { toggle() }
    }


    // MARK: - METHODS
    func updateUI() {
        background.backgroundColor = toggleState.color
        background.layer.addShadow()
    }

    func toggle() {
        background.backgroundColor = toggleState.color
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_onColor` and `_offColor` are static, so there will not be a separate `_onColor` and `_offColor` for each instance of your class.\

You should make `_onColor` and `_offColor` non-static, and remove the `color` property of `ToggleState`, and instead add such a method in your *class*:

```
func color(forToggleState state: ToggleState) {
    switch state {
    case .on:
        return _onColor
    case .off:
        return _offColor
    }
}
```

Instead of `toggleState.color`, you should write:

```
color(forToggleState: toggleState)
```

`color` shouldn't be a property of `ToggleState` because to compute it, you need information from another object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Especially the last paragraph is helpful.

Comment: @AlexanderHeld If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!